# How can I make my leaderboard command sorted from highest to lowest on discord.js?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

This is my current code:

```js
function leaderboardembed() {
    const filtered = client.points.filter(p => p.guild === message.guild.id).array();
    let orilent;
    const sorted = filtered.sort((a, b) => b.vouches - a.vouches );
    let embeds = [];
    let j = 0;
    let first = (10)
    let maxnum = 50;
    orilent = sorted.length;
    if(isNaN(maxnum)) {
        console.log("maximum_leaderboard NOT A NUMBER")
        maxnum = 50;}
        if (maxnum > sorted.length) 
            maxnum = sorted.length + (10 - Number(String(sorted.length/10).slice(2)));
        if (maxnum < 10) maxnum = 10;
            for (let i = 10; i <= maxnum; i += 10) {
                const top = sorted.splice(0, 10);
        
                const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle(`\`${message.guild.name}\` | Leaderboard`)
                    .setTimestamp()
                    .setDescription(`Top ${i<orilent?i:orilent}/${orilent} Ranking:`)
                    .setColor(embedcolor);
                for (const data of top) {
                    j++;
                    try {
                        embed.addField(`**${j}**. \`${data.usertag}\``, ` | **Vouches:** \`${data.vouch}\``);
                    } catch {
                        embed.addField(`**${j}**. \`${data.usertag}\``, ` | **Vouches:** \`${data.vouch}\``);
                    }
                }
                embeds.push(embed);
            }
            return embeds;
        }
        async function leaderboard() {
            let currentPage = 0;
            const embeds = leaderboardembed();
            if (embeds.length == 1)
                return message.channel.send(embeds[0]).catch(e=>console.log("ranking: " + e))
        const lbembed = await message.channel.send(
            `**Current Page - ${currentPage + 1}/${embeds.length}**`,
            embeds[currentPage]).catch(e=>console.log("ranking: " + e));

        try {
            await lbembed.react("⏪");
            await lbembed.react("⏹");
            await lbembed.react("⏩");
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }

        const filter = (reaction, user) => ["⏪", "⏹", "⏩"].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && message.author.id === user.id;
        const collector = lbembed.createReactionCollector(filter, {
            time: 60000
        });

        collector.on("collect", async (reaction, user) => {
            try {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === "⏩") {
                    if (currentPage < embeds.length - 1) {
                        currentPage++;
                        lbembed.edit(`**Current Page - ${currentPage + 1}/${embeds.length}**`, embeds[currentPage]);
                    }
                } else if (reaction.emoji.name === "⏪") {
                    if (currentPage !== 0) {
                        --currentPage;
                        lbembed.edit(`**Current Page - ${currentPage + 1}/${embeds.length}**`, embeds[currentPage]);
                    }
                } else {
                    collector.stop();
                    reaction.message.reactions.removeAll();
                }
                await reaction.users.remove(message.author.id);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        });
    }
```

This is how it displays when doing the command

[image]

The problem is that there's about 1000 members and some don't have the "vouches" and id rather just display the people that have the highest to lowest.

Here's an example of what I'm aiming it to be like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to sort all of them, you do need them all in an array. Otherwise, it will be excessively difficult. Here is a simple sort function that JavaScript provides for us:

```js
var ranks = [7, 2, 9, 5, 10, 110]
ranks.sort() //don’t use this, this would put 10, 110, 2 etc since it’s alphabetical, you need to specify how to sort it
ranks.sort((a, b)=> a - b) //2, 5, 7, 9, 10, 110
//to reverse that
ranks.sort((a, b) => b-a)
```